# Computable function that enumerates the primitive recursive functions

Tags: computability

I'm trying to construct a computable function $f:\omega^2\to\omega$ such that

- For all $e\in\omega$, $x\mapsto f(e,x)$ is primitive recursive.
- If $g:\omega\to\omega$ is primitive recursive, then there exists $e\in\omega$ such that $f(e,x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in\omega$.

What I've tried so far:

By the normal form theorem there's a primitive recursive unary function $U$, and a trinary recursive relation $T_1$ such that if $f$ is a unary partial recursive function, then it has a code $e$ such that:
$$f(x)=U(\mu yT_1(e,x,y))$$

So it seems like there should be a computable relation $Q_1$ that determines if $e$ is a code for a unary partial recursive function, and then we have a computable function $c$ defined by

$$c(e,x)=\begin{cases}U(\mu y(T_1(e,x,y)) &\mbox{if }Q(e)\\0 &\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

The notes I'm working from codes finite sequences of numbers as follows

$$\langle x_0,\dots,x_n\rangle:=2^{x_0+1}3^{x_1+1}\dots p_n^{x_n+1}$$

And we have primitive recursive functions/predicates like $seq(e)$ that says $e$ codes a sequence, $lth(e)$ that outputs the length of $e$, and $(e)_i$ that outputs the $i$-th number in the sequence coded by $e$.

The partial recursive functions are then coded by

- $\langle 0\rangle$ corresponds to $O$ the zero function
- $\langle 1\rangle$ corresponds to $S$ the successor function
- $\langle 2,n,i\rangle$ ($1\le i\le n$) the projection functions
- $\langle 3,a_1,\dots,a_n,b\rangle$ for the composition $\chi(\psi_1(x)\dots,\psi_n(x))$ where $b$ codes $\chi$, $a_i$ codes $\psi_i$.
- $\langle 4,a,b\rangle$ for primitive recursion from $\chi,\psi$.

And just for completeness

- $\langle 5,a\rangle$ for $\mu$-recursion.

So if $e$ codes a unary primitive recursion function, we have $(e)_1\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and some obvious requirements like $(e)_1=2\implies lth(e)=3\wedge(e)_2=(e)_3=1$.

But then it starts to turn into a mess when I consider composition, because I need $b$ to code an $n$-ary primitive recursive function, so do I need to find a primitive recursive relation that decides if $b$ does so?

So I need $Q_n(e)$ that says $e$ codes an $n$-ary primitive recursive function, so we have $\chi_{Q_n}(0)=0$ for all $n\ge 1$.

But then to define the $Q_n$ it seems like I would need to somehow use all the $Q_n$s simultaneously, which doesn't seem allowable.

And at that point I give up.

Also I've tried searching for R. Péter's construction, but the closest I came was a German version of her book (at least I think that's what it was), but unfortunately I don't speak German so it wasn't very useful to me personally.

So, is my approach completely wrong? If so what should be I trying, if not how do I get around my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path with the *encoding* of the primitive recursive functions. One remark, the $Q_n$s you need should recognize codes for *primitive recursive* functions, not for *partial recursive* ones.

On the other hand, you're out for a long trek if you want to define your $f$ from first principles in terms of primitive recursion and minimization. There's gotta be an easier way. However *what* that easier way is, depends on which tools you have at your disposal at this place in your course (if you're following a course).

If you have the full Church-Turing thesis available, it will generally be sufficient to argue *informally* that $f$ can be programmed in your favorite computing formalism.

Alternatively, if you at least have *some* more friendly formalism than raw Turing machines or primitive-recursion-and-minimization proved equivalent to either of those, then most probably it will be easier to prove that your $f$ is expressible *there* and then appeal to your earlier equivalence result.

As for your technical problems with the $Q$s, note that whether $x=\langle 4,a,b\rangle$ codes for a p.r. function depends on whether $a$ and $b$ *which are both strictly smaller than $x$* do. So you can define your $Q$ by ordinary (not primitive) recursion on its argument.

More technically, if you're stuck in a primitive-recursion world, one option would be to define the function
$$ K(n) = \langle k_0,k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n \rangle $$
where $k_i$ is $m\ge 1$ if $i$ defines an $m$-argument primitive recursive function and $0$ if it doesn't define a primitive recursive function at all.

With a bit of elbow grease you can then define a way to find $k_{n+1}$ given $K(n)$ and $n+1$, given the tools to manipulate Gödel numbers it looks like you already have, and therefore define $K$ itself by primitive recursion.

Then your $f(e,x)$ could start by computing $K(e)$ and checking that its last element is $1$.

---

An **alternative** to representing the $Q_n$s separately would be to simply decide that at each level everything that does *not* have one of the forms you give special meaning to (including if it starts with $5$), is by definition a code for the zero function -- of whichever many arguments you need it to have.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I am limited to Turing machines, but I think your $K$ route will work so I'm going to try that.

Comment: @RJM: The $K$ route is really most meaningful if you're forced to work with primitive recursion _specifically_. If you're doing Turing machines directly it is probably just as easy to do unrestricted recursion directly, using the tape as a call stack.

Comment: (But I'm a computer scientist, so I cannot help but worry about the efficiency of various solutions :-)

Comment: To be honest I'm not entirely sure what unrestricted recursion means (I'm new to Computability), but the $K$ route turned out to be pretty easy so I'm going to leave it at that.

Comment: @RJM: unrestricted recursion is when $f(...)$ is defined by an expression (or procedure) that (in some cases) depends on values of $f$ for other arguments.